# recv dont send me a -1 on client socket close()

Tags: c, linux, sockets, posix

SERVER CODE

```
...
client_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &client_address,     &client_address_len);
...
for (;;) {
    if ( recv(client_socket, recived_buffer, MAX_MSG_LENGTH, 0) < 0 ) {
        perror("ERROR leyendo el socket");
        exit(1)
    }
}
```

if i kill the client the server lopps indefinitely...

Any tip?

Answer (score 11):

When a client closes a connection, the server-side [`recv()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) call will return a value of 0.

From the [**`recv(2)`**](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) manpage:

> Return Value
>
> These calls return the number of bytes received, or -1 if an error occurred. The return value will be 0 when the peer has performed an orderly shutdown.

---

It may also be important to note that the [`recv()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) call will block until there is data available to read.   If you want to not block, you need to be sure to set the socket to non-blocking or use [`select()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) or [`poll()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) to see if there is incoming data before calling [`recv()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv).

Answer (score 2):

recv returns 0 - when the peer closes the connection, the other part interprets it as an EOF